# How know CSS version - ASP.NET - VS Community 2013

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio

I created a default **ASP.NET project** with **Visual Studio Community 2013** and I would like to know the **CSS and HTML version** that it use.

Anybody know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html and css rendering engines change depending on the browser the client is using. There's no "css and html version" for a project.

You can try http://caniuse.com/ to find out whether or not a browser allows you to use a certain css feature.